# Capture credentials and use to log in to JIRA

Tags: svn, authentication, scripting, hook, jira

I am using the standard SVN-JIRA pre-commit hook to enforce users to enter a JIRA issue ID as a comment when the commit while using [this JIRA plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/CMMT/JIRA+Commit+Acceptance). It calls a python [**script**](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/attachment/30259/jira-client.py) which logs in to JIRA using a hard-coded username and password. This brings two problems:

1. IT security policy is against this password written in a file.
2. A user who has access to SVN but no access to JIRA can still update the JIRA issue

So I want to use the committer's credentials to log in to JIRA.

Now what is the best way in your opinion to go about it? I am not very sure about the access control mechanism in place. We use the same username for SVN (svn-acl on AIX server),Windows,JIRA but passwords are different so I am assuming is some LDAP/AD combination.

Two improvisations I could think of quickly, though both are just that - not very clean/elegant:

1. There is no other auth info being passed to SVN , so maybe have a VBscript pop-up (I am using TortoiseSVN client+Subclipse) which asks for JIRA password when commit happens (you can auto populate the ' author ' from the Python script. Or launch a JIRA login window somehow.
2. A dummy SSO - enforce users to keep same passwords for logins. Use creds from either Win/SVN to log-in to JIRA. Makeshift, as it is dependent on human behavior and differing password policies. When commits are not allowed due to this, you are not clean

I am open to 3rd party solutions (Fisheye ??) but preferred is a hack/script.

Comment: What is the purpose of logging into Jira?  Are you using this plugin?  https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/CMMT/JIRA+Commit+Acceptance

Comment: yes.. this is the plugin.. updated the question

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible for what you are looking for, because:

1. No authentication information is passed to SVN hook script, so you cannot make use of the user + password to logon to JIRA
2. Even you can get the user + password in SVN, as seems you are using different authentication mechanism for SVN, the password in SVN is not going to work on JIRA (which use an LDAP)

Honestly, I just don't see using one special account to connect to JIRA as a problem.  Your second point is in fact something should happen.  As long as something happened in SVN related to a JIRA issue, we should update status in JIRA, regardless who does the commit.

If you agree on that, what is left is the plain password in script.  There are lots of way to solve that I think.  There are cryptic libraries for Python I believe, which you can make use of.

Comment: Adrian, +1 for the point of view but does not answer my question. Updated the question to address your point 1 and 2. Now about `plain password in script` currently its using my JIRA ID+password which a) Will need to be updated regularly and b) Is person dependent from process point of view.

Comment: The added point doesn't make the situation easier to solve :)  I think you may look into @Logan's answer.  The pre-requisit is, authentication of Jira and SVN needs to be done by same backend in order to have the *possibility* to achieve what you want to do.  By the way, popping up screen to ask for password seems not going to work either, as I believe in SVN's protocol, there is no way to capture and transfer such kind of extra information

Comment: I get you point.. but any other way you can think .. an API.. maybe a PERL library ?

Comment: It is nothing to do with what's the language or api to use.  Things simply not logically possible.  If you need to do authentication for JIRA, you need to get the related information.  However there is no way for you to get it in SVN side.  If you insist to use the SVN user to logon to JIRA (which I don't see any reason for that), either you are storing all JIRA users' password for the SVN script to lookup, or find some way in JIRA that allow you to "impersonate" anyone without actual authentication.  I believe neither of these is possible/satisfactory

Comment: Last resort is to make a custom-made client, which do the SVN commit and corresponding JIRA update in it.  By doing so you can ask user to input whatever password required.  However I just don't know why anyone would want to go this trouble way while you can simply connect to JIRA with one special account and do the work.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use [Crowd](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/overview) for authentication for both Jira and Subversion. If the user references a Jira issue in their SVN commit comment, the comment will be added to the relevant Jira issue. As for restricting users with SVN access but no Jira access, you could add a post-commit hook that checks Crowd to verify that the user has Jira access. I'm not sure why someone would be allowed to commit source code but not comment on bugs, but that's up to you.